# UIImageView renders image differently to original

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

The image on the right is the one that I produced in photoshop. I then stripped all text and put it in an image view, as soon as I did that there was a change in colour and the vertical line lost it sharpness. Has anyone else run into a similar problem? What do I do?
[alt text http://grab.by/1DuZ](http://grab.by/1DuZ)

Comment: is that screen shot from the simulator or from the device?

Comment: Device, though it appears the same in Interface Builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the dimensions correct? Is the position of the image an integer? If these cases antialiasing will slightly blur your image.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the most likely problem is that he's aligned the image view on a non-integer coordinate in X or Y, or that he's applied a transform of some sort to the view.

Comment: Yes the dimensions are correct, and Yes the position is an integer. I have applied no transformation.

Comment: Try using the Core Animation instrument in Instruments, and selecting the Color Misaligned Images option.  It should color any views or layers that are non-pixel-aligned in your application.  Maybe a superview somewhere in the hierarchy isn't aligned properly.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to be careful of is that if your image is an odd number of pixels in either dimension then centering it onscreen will cause it to be misaligned.  Imagine if you had a 1x1 image (just one pixel) and tried to center it perfectly onscreen.  It can't be done because the screen is an even number of pixels wide and high.  This is why it's best to always use even dimensioned images whenever possible.

Comment: Too true, just found this out the hard way. Image just looked bad no matter what until I added a pixel in either side to the UIImageView. So a workaround for odd-pixel images is to make the UIImageView containing the image be an even number of pixels. Half pixel off definitely looks better than a blurred icon, especially when the icon is already anti-aliased and small.